# Trying to Validate that an input is not empty then link to another page if it is not, can't get link to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm using a form that has a very basic validation (it just checks if the input is not empty) and I want to have the submit button link to another page only if the form is valid but I'm having issues. Using the code below the validation works fine but the page links to google regardless of if the form has any data in the input fields or not. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple here??

Thanks in advance!

```js
$('.create-tournament-form').on('submit', function(e) {

    $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
        }
        else if( $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select').val() !== "" ) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-top">
        <div class="form-top-left">
            <h3>Step 3 / 3</h3>
            <p>Some More Info:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-top-right">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-bottom">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Something</label>
            <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Something" class="required form-email form-control" id="form-email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Something Else</label>
            <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Something Else" class="required form-email form-control" id="form-email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-button-wrap">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
            <button id="create-tournament-submit" type="submit" class="btn">Create!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-progress-bar">
            <div class="progress-circle"></div>
            <div class="progress-circle"></div>
            <div class="progress-circle circle-current"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why you cant use jQuery validate plugin? https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that the else statement is iterating through all of the inputs and if any one of them is not empty, then it sends you off to google.

A quick modification to get it doing what you want would look something like this :

```
    var okToCont=true;
$(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select').each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                okToCont=false;
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            }
});
if (okToCont) window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

however there's almost certainly a better way of doing this.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. Unfortunately after implementing that as follows `$('.create-tournament-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var okToCont=true;
  $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select').each(function() {
    if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('input-error');
      okToCont=false;
     }
    else {
     $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    }
  });
  if (okToCont) window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }); `

my button isn't doing anything anymore?

Comment: I think the problem you are experiencing now is that the form post event is occurring when the form contents are valid. This will "overwrite" your attempt to change the window location to www.google.com. What happens is your javascript tries to change the location, but then the form default behaviour kicks in and makes the location wherever the form is posting to (I can't see this in your example).  Take a look at this fiddle,  it simplifies it and demonstrates the issue : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/linskin/x50o48h8/13/)